# Compiling error when trying to change tabBar icon background color (using Sass) in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, compass-sass

I used Sencha command to generate the app for me, and am now branding it using their Sass/Css documentation. You are supposed to be able to use the Sencha mixin for changing the bg color of the default icons in your tab bar:

```
@include mask-by-background($bg-color, $contrast, $style);
```

However no matter what combination of variables and values I use, I always get the compiling error "error app.scss (Line 38 of _gradients.scss: Properties are only allowed within rules, directives, mixin includes, or other properties.)" I am using the most updated versions of Sencha Touch, the SDK, and Sencha command.

Here is some of what I have tried so far:

```
$bg-color: #f2f2f2;
@include mask-by-background($bg-color, 80%, 'matte');


$bg-color: #f2f2f2;
@include mask-by-background($bg-color, $contrast: 80%, 'matte');


$bg-color: #f2f2f2;
@include mask-by-background($bg-color, $contrast: 80%, $style:'matte');
```

I even tried:

```
$bg-color: #f2f2f2;
$contrast: 80%;
@include mask-by-background($bg-color, $contrast, 'matte');
```

I am trying to use compass to change the css, instead of having to write huge rules like ".x-tabbar-red.x-docked-bottom .x-tab-active .x-button-icon" to override styling. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I've been using to change background of tab panel and corresponding pictos.

```
$base-color: #fff;
$active-color: #08ae2d;

$base-gradient: 'glossy';
$tabs-dark: darken($base-color, 80%);
$tabs-dark-active-color: saturate($active-color, 20%);
$tabs-bottom-active-gradient: 'recessed';
```

This is for dark theme of mine, you'd definitely change color levels as per your need. And for more info regarding css mixins related to tabBar, you can refer [the link](https://github.com/nelstrom/compass-sencha-touch/blob/master/stylesheets/sencha-touch/default/widgets/_tabs.scss)

Comment: It appears 2.2 changes theming quite a bit, so some of this may become irrelevant. Thanks tho! I had looked into the _tabs.scss but it was over a year old and I couldn't get it working in my project.